# How to remove certain characters from a string? [Python]

Tags: python, string, character

Say i have a string called cool and cool is set to "cool°"

```
cool = "cool°"
```

how do i remove the degree symbol from the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since strings are immutable, use the replace function to reassign `cool`

```
cool = "cool°"
cool = cool.replace("°","")
cool
'cool'
```

Answer (score 3):

If they are at the end of the string use `str.rstrip`:

```
cool = "cool°"

cool = cool.rstrip("°")
print(cool)
cool
```